# Chained inheritance of empty classes, still necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, base-class, empty-class

**Are there still good reasons to use chainned base cases rather than a flat multiple inheritance?**

It used to be the case that some classes were designed to be inherted in chain. I think this was to force the empty base class optimization.
I understand this is how Boost.Operators were designed.

```
struct empty{};

template<class Base = empty>
struct A : Base{}; 

template<class Base = empty>
struct B : Base{}; 

template<class Base = empty>
struct C : Base{};

struct S : A<B<C<>>>{};

int main(){static_assert(sizeof(S)==1, "!");}
```

**Is this necessary anymore in new compilers (today is 2019),  or I can ditch all that complexity and live with normal inheritance?**

```
struct A{}; 

struct B{}; 

struct C{};

struct S : A, B, C{};

int main(){static_assert( sizeof(S) == 1 , "!");}
```

does it serve any primary or secondary purpose anymore?

Comment: See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/optimizing-the-layout-of-empty-base-classes-in-vs2015-update-2-3/

Comment: You should introduce some virtual functions. Then it might become relevant for more compilers.

Comment: @Justin, ok, then it seems that for not having wildly large classes this is still needed for VisualStudio (and that they came up with their own workaround.)

Comment: EBO is optional, so in both cases, assert might fire.

Comment: @Jarod42, EBO is optional for the compilers to implement? I guess this craziness will end when C++ rediscovers 0. (when `sizeof(S) == 0`) http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html

Comment: Even with EBO, the size of an empty struct might not be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard states in **`[class.derived]/7`** that:

> A base class subobject **may be** of zero size.

This means that EBO is not mandatory for compilers to implement. However nearly all compilers implement it.

From C++20 onwards, there is the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute which can be applied to the empty member subobjects:

> The empty member subobjects are permitted to be optimized out just like the empty bases if they use the attribute `[[no_unique_address]]`. Taking the address of such member results in an address that may equal the address of some other member of the same object.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how the attribute is used in the context of inhertance, the examples are for member variables: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address

Comment: Not sure I get you. The subobjects of inherited classes will have size 0 anyway in the derived class due to EBO. Can you give an example of what you are want to achieve?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, I was just wondering where the attribute would fit in my example.